# Change value of input when an option is chosen in the select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple `select` with some values :

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1">First value</option>
    <option value="2">Second value</option>
</select>
```

I have a simple `input` text :

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="60" value="Text">
```

I want to change the value of my input text by Text 2 if i select the option "Second value" in my select.

I want to do it in jQuery, but i don't know how, thanks .

Comment: jQuery Learning Center is a good place to start: http://learn.jquery.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("select[name=test]").change(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    $("#title").val("Text " + value);
});
```

Comment: Close but no need for a downvote when a comment will suffice... That would use the value not the `.text()` of the option.

Comment: @Popnoodles -- OP doesnt want the text of the option - it says change the input value to "Text 2" if the second option is selected...

Comment: Oh I must have read it wrong sorry. **Downvoter care to comment why this was downvoted?** (Maybe it was to discourage encouraging this type of question)